# Cant transfer values because of "freed objects"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to pass lat\lon to other instance.
I added call to lat\lon of decive and saving them in `NSString`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    lon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    latValueNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", lat];
    lanValueNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", lan];

}
```

The `lat,lon` are float type.

When i'm aceesing to this interface

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

In the debuuger mode i see the valuses of lat,lon (float) but cant get to them. when I accesing to `latValueNSString/lanValueNSString`  i see it "`freed object`"

How can I pass those values? where is my mistake?
tried the same thing with `NSSunmber` and the same problem

Comment: Did you use retain/strong properties ?

Comment: What you mean? I just declared the `NSString` and `float` types in the `.h` file.

Comment: Than it is your responsibility to retain and release it.

Comment: OK i am using retain\release...Its not changing anything

Comment: post the code where you declare them.

Comment: I simply define : `latValueNSString = [[NSString alloc] init];` and `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* latValueNSString ;` but the problem I think is that it never 'finish' and getting out with values its getting into `didUpdateToLocation` every second and setting it over and over. When i setting it hard-coded I getting it back correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning an `autoreleased` object (`[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", lat]` will return an a`utoreleased` object), that's why you are getting that error.
You need to retain the value for further use.

Just change your method like:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    lon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    self.latValueNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", lat];
    self.lanValueNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", lan];

}
```

or

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    lon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    latValueNSString = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", lat] retain];
    lanValueNSString = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", lan] retain];

}
```

Comment: Or switch to Objective-C ARC.

Answer (score -1):

Use `assign` property for float variables and no need to release it. For `NSString` variables, `retain/release` is fine.